# javascript promise return recursively to index

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so I've got a loop like so:

```
underscore.each(dom.paramArray, function(value, i) {
     fetchDataFromServerWithParams(value, i);
});
```

In my current example it loops 3 times, idealy like: 0,1,2
However, when I log the index of the function called, it logs: 1,0,2, why ? 
And how can I get it to call the function recursively, so first it will process the function with index:0, then index:1, and lastly, index:2

I think it has something to do with the functions I am calling (buildResult and buildSubResult), but Im really not sure?

The function that is called by the loop looks like:

```
function fetchDataFromServerWithParams(param, index) {
        //Create promise
        let getData = $.ajax({
            headers: {
                Accept : "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
                "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
            },
            type: "GET",
            url: configuration.apiEndpoint,
            data: { id: param},
            dataType: "json"
        });

        //When done processing promise, build result
        getData.then(function (data) {
            let generatedData;
            console.log(index);
            if(index === 0) {
                generatedData = buildResult(data);
            } else {
                $.each($("ul.material a"), function( index, value ) {
                    var target = $(this).parent();

                    if($(this).data("id") == param) { //Refactor later to ===
                        target.parent().addClass("open-folder");
                        target.parent().parent().find("ul").addClass("open-folder");
                        generatedData = buildSubResult(data, target);
                    }
                });
            }
        }), function(xhr, status, error) {
            // Handle errors for any of the actions
            handleError(error);
        };
    }
```

Comment: It's because the calls are asynchronous. They may be sent in the order 1, 2, 3, but you're at the mercy of the receiving server as to the order it deals with them and how fast the response takes to come back. Hence why you receive them in a different order.

Comment: Yeah, thought so... any ideas to how to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the issue? I presume to do with the order of the elements created by `buildSubresult`? If so you could just `sort()` them once all requests have completed - or add them in the correct place at the time of insertion in to the DOM

Comment: The issue is that it performs buildSubResults with index: 2, before index: 1 - They need to execute syncronously, not async... 
It has to call the functions and execute in order: 0,1,2, instead of 0,2,1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library or any other library for this purpose

also you can change the line

```
getData.then(function (data) {
```

to

```
return getData.then(function (data) {
```

and use this code instead of your underscore loop

```
(function sequenceCall(index){
   fetchDataFromServerWithParams(dom.paramArray[index], index).then(function(){
        sequenceCall(index+1);
    });
})(0);
```

Comment: If getting an error: c(...).then is not a function on this line:

Comment: fetchDataFromServerWithParams(dom.paramArray[index], index).then(function(){
        sequenceCall(index+1);
    });

Comment: and i've changed the line to "return getData", but that gives me that error?

Comment: Nevermind, my bad, it works as a charm! :) Thank you SO much! :)